# Use the iPad's Camera for Stream in Localhost

Tags: swift, camera, stream, localhost

1. On my Mac Book Pro, I have a MAMP server.
   Address: http://localhost:8888

I create a simple page with a video tag:

2. On my iPad Pro, I created an application that uses the camera of the iPad.
3. I would like to know how to send the video from the iPad's camera to my localhost server (on the video tag).

I have no idea how to do this.
Can you help me?

Thank you so much

Note: The iPad and the MacBook are not connected by a cable.
The iPad and MacBook are in 2 different rooms.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with apple is the video format which can be streamed are not supported by other browsers (m3u8 format) which cannot be viewed in chrome / mozilla only works in safari browsers. so the solution for this is to capture images from iPad (frame extractor)

Below link will help to do it
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-camera-frames-extraction-d2c0f80ed05a

after extracting the images send this images to the localhost in the form of MJPEG format. and you can view this in you browser player.

Make sure you use GCD and Autorelease pool or while sending the images the iPad UI may freeze as it is a heavy task to extract and send it to server at the same time.

Hope this helps.